# Is there any good micro USB cable (not loose)?

Tags: usb, hardware, connection-issues

I'm not sure if this could be considered as an Android question, but it's definetely related to Android, since this kind of cable became a standard for mobile devices recently.

The thing is, I have to work plugging and unplugging pretty often (I'm a developer), and I noticed most of the cables (or device/cable pairs) seem to be loose, some of them even lose the connectivity sometimes, and I've been looking for different kind of cables, and I really didn't find anything satisfying.

I feel there isn't much I can do, I just wanted to know if my cables are "bad", or most of micro usb connectors are just that way.

*Edited to try to meet the requirements of the FAQ.*

Comment: With my HTC Desire all the 3rd party cables I have bought seem to make a looser connection than the one supplied with the phone.

Comment: This really isn't a question suited for this site. This sort of question is, in fact, expressly discouraged. Please see the FAQ. If you can re-word the question to be less soliciting discussion, please do so. Otherwise it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The micro USB cables that come with BlackBerries are great, the connection is not loose at all.  (I've tried one with my Android phone).  So I'd have to say that your cables are indeed "bad".

Answer (score 0):

I agree it probably fine for day to day charging etc. But for dev work you may be wiser to use the big end to connect reconnect the device.

Comment: it would be wiser, but not practical... since there are few developers, few devices, and we all have to try different models. And actually there aren't so many cables, I wonder where they go...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a USB extension or port multiplier would be a decent workaround? If you used an extension cable, you can avoid damaging the mini-USB port on the phone since you generally plug/remove the extension plug instead of the mini-plug.

Comment: This is more or less, what the other answer is about, if I understood you correctly, but that would be good just if the devices were standing at my desk most of the times. Otherwise I would need something to "lock" the cable to the device... not really nice